# Dates formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Dates formula in Excel - I have attached an image that asks my question.

[image]

Comment: The `NETWORKDAYS` function may be of some use here, but I fear it may be an iterative process for all but the smallest values in column C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is:

```
=WORKDAY(D7,C7,[Optional list of Holidays])
```

which you put in D8 and then drag down.
Your cells have to be in a Date format.
The help file says for the Holidays list:

- **Holidays**  Optional. An optional list of one or more dates to exclude from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contain the dates or an array constant (array: Used to build single formulas that produce multiple results or that operate on a group of arguments that are arranged in rows and columns. An array range shares a common formula; an array constant is a group of constants used as an argument.) of the serial numbers that represent the dates.

Note that in your example, there is no holiday between 2/22/2011 and 2/24/2011, so D17 should be 2/24/2011, and the others modified from there.  Also D20 is not 10 days from 2/28/2011.

Comment: Thanks, how would I exclude holidays if there were in the list? Would I have to make a seperate list of holiday dates and include it in the WORKDAY formula?

Comment: @Mike, You can add a list of holidays as a third parameter, see the help files.  I'll edit my answer.